# Play PCM data in .NET Framework 2?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav, pcm

I have a stream of u-Law compressed PCM data I am extracting from a Camera, I need to play this out the speakers?  Anybody know how?  I've tried decoding the u-Law into normal WAV Data and then use SoundPlayer but it never seems to work!  Always SoundPlayer only supports PCM Data?

I know the sounds ok, because I have saved it to a file (using a custom createWavHeader method) and iTunes can play it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows comes with an ACM codec to convert u-law to PCM. You can use [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) and use the WaveFileReader and the WaveFormatConversionStream to get a PCM stream you can play easily.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, there is a *freeware* library [lizPlay](http://libzplay.sourceforge.net/) providing PCM playing capabilities. Worth considering as developers of lizPlay pay special attention to ensure there is a version that is free of patent infringement issues.