# Play wav file when Button is clicked and pause wav file when same button is released?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, wav

I am looking for a way to turn an ordinary C# Winform button into a sort of push button to play a wav file when pressed and held in and pause it when you release the button.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing a .WAV file in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284322/playing-a-wav-file-in-net)

Comment: You can script the Button.MouseUp and -Down events to start and stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply play the file when the mouse is down and stop the player when the mouse is up again:

```
SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(pathToWavFile);

private void yourButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    soundPlayer.Play();
}
private void yourButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    soundPlayer.Stop();
}
```