# The Name 'My' does not exist in current context in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Waterfall, 
        AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

I'm trying to play a WAV file that is inside of Resources acording to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc61hbxh.aspx

I get the error The Name 'My' does not exist in current context in Visual Studio 2013

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using C# perhaps and not VB.NET?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6fouji - i'm trying to do this on VB.NET. am I not suspost to?

Comment: You should be using VB.NET. You aren't.

Comment: If you want it it C# .net look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284322/playing-a-wav-file-in-net

Comment: @WyattJames You say it should be C# but you link to a VB article.   Can you clarify for sure which language you want to do this in?

Comment: I want this done in C# @Dijkgraaf "The type or namespace name "SoundPlayer" could not be found

Comment: The path to the audio I want to play is Resources\cupidshuffle.wav

Comment: `My.Computer` is a VB.NET construct. That's why you don't see it in C#.

Comment: Add `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

My.Computer is providing access to the local computer resources. You could try the code on a windows form application using visual basic .net

here's the detail of My Class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0.aspx